# Filter sorting in sonar

Tags: filter, dashboard, sonarqube

Is it possible to configure a sonar filter to list projects sorted by Last Analysis. I know you can click on Last Analysis to sort, but can this be setup to sort by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're in the edit/create filter page just click on the column you want to sort with :)

Comment: I thought I had done that but it wasn't sticking for some reason.  Looks like it works now. Thank you for answering my duh-duh question.